# How do I create a PR using GitHub Actions working?

Tags: github, github-actions, devops, github-api, cicd

I keep getting this error:

> pull request create failed: GraphQL: Resource not accessible by integration (createPullRequest)

Even though I have granted `GITHUB_TOKEN` every permission.

Here's my workflow:

```yaml
name: Pull Request Action

on:
  push:
  workflow_dispatch:

env:
  GH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}        
   
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check out repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Git
        run: |
          git config --global user.email "github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com"
          git config --global user.name "github-actions[bot]"

      - name: Install jq
        run: |
          sudo apt-get -y install jq

      - name: Update Config Params and Create Pull Requests
        run: |
          #urls=$(curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ubiquity/devpool-directory/development/projects.json | jq -r '.urls[]')
          urls="https://github.com/EtherealGlow/ubiquibot-pr-qa"
          for url in $urls
          do
            repoName=$(basename $url)
            ownerName=$(echo $url | awk -F/ '{print $(NF-1)}')

            git clone $url $repoName
            cd $repoName

            defaultBranch=$(git branch --show-current)

            ### update configs ###
            # The configurations update code goes here

            declare -A param_mapping=(
              ["evm-network-id"]="network-id chain-id"
              ["price-multiplier"]="base-multiplier"
              #add more configs as needed  
            )

            # Iterate over the mapping and perform updates using sed
            for new_param in "${!param_mapping[@]}"
            do
              old_params="${param_mapping[$new_param]}"
              for old_param in $old_params
              do
                sed -i "s/\b$old_param\b/$new_param/g" .github/ubiquibot-config.yml
              done
            done
            git add .
            git commit -m "fix: use latest ubiquibot config setup"
            gh pr create --base $defaultBranch --head $defaultBranch --fill
            cd ..
          done
```

I thought it would just create a PR.

Answer (score 1):

Giving GitHub Actions permission to create and/or approve pull requests can introduce a number of security issues, so there is a seperate policy in your actions setting that restricts Actions from Creating and Approving pull requests that must be enabled seperately.

See:

- https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/admin/policies/enforcing-policies-for-your-enterprise/enforcing-policies-for-github-actions-in-your-enterprise#preventing-github-actions-from-creating-or-approving-pull-requests

> You can choose to allow or prevent GitHub Actions workflows from creating or approving pull requests.
>
> By default, when you create a new enterprise, workflows are not allowed to create or approve pull requests.
>
> 1. In the top-right corner of GitHub.com, click your profile photo, then click Your enterprises.
> 2. In the list of enterprises, click the enterprise you want to view.
> 3. In the enterprise account sidebar, click Policies. Under "Policies", click Actions.
> 4. Under "Workflow permissions", use the Allow GitHub Actions to create and approve pull requests setting to configure whether GITHUB_TOKEN can create and approve pull requests.
> 5. Click <kbd>Save</kbd> to apply the settings.

The same setting can be found in the organization settings and the repository settings:

[image: Go to Settings, Actions]

[image: Scroll down to set the permissions for the token]

And when doing a pull request across branches, you may have to provide your own PAT token or Oauth App Token because the token created for Actions is only authorized in the repo hosting the workflow.

Comment: Ps if you're trying to create a PR in a different repo than the one hosting the workflow you'll have to provide a separate PAT or Oauth App Token.